# How to bind data to a graph before jquery dialog window pops up?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am developing a web application which connects to an Azure database. I am trying to generate a graph based on user selection from a radiolist and from two inputted time parameters. I want to display this graph in a pop up jquery dialog box when the user clicks the request graph button.

My problem is that the data is binded on click of the request graph button as well as calling the jquery dialog box, and so the jquery dialog box pops up but no graph is displayed. Is there any way I can get the data to bind to the graph before the jquery is executed and so display the graph in the pop up box.

My aspx code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#Chart1").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });
        $("#RequestGraph_Btn").on("click", function () {
            $("#Chart1").dialog("open");

            return false;
        });

    });
</script>


<asp:Button ID="RequestGraph_Btn" runat="server" Text="Request Graph" style="height:114px;width:147px;" OnClick="RequestGraph_Btn_Click" />


<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height ="300px" Width ="700">
    <series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series1" ToolTip ="Value of Time:#VALX Value of AP:#VALY">
        </asp:Series>
    </series>
    <chartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY Title ="Atmosphere">
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX Title ="Time">
            </AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </chartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

And my aspx.cs code:

```
protected void RequestGraph_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioSelection = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;

        bindGraph();
    }


    private void bindGraph()
    {
        // retrieve connection from configuration settings 
        connection = new SqlConnection(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DataConnectionString").ToString());

        // Calling SQL query 
        command = new SqlCommand("SELECT time, "+radioSelection+" FROM Buoy3v3 WHERE time > '"+TextBox1_fromDate.Text+"' AND time < '"+TextBox2_toDate.Text+"';", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        ds = new DataSet();

        //connection open
        connection.Open();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

        // fill data set
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        //connection close
        connection.Close();

        //add the data to the Chart and select x and y axis 

        Chart1.DataSource = ds;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "time";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = radioSelection;

    }
```

Thanks to anyone who can provide any help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add the script to the page during the postback itself using `ClientSriptManager` that's on the `Page` object.

Remove your existing Javascript code block and try to build it in a way such as this.

```
protected void RequestGraph_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radioSelection = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;

    bindGraph();

    String csname1 = "PopupScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
    {
        string script = @"$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#Chart1").dialog("open");
        });";

        StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
        cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript>");
        cstext1.Append(script);
        cstext1.Append("</script>");

        // add script to page
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
    }
}
```

This will cause the Javascript to be attached to the page and be executed on load rather than on click.

Basically, once your *Button_Click* event fires, it will do the work within *bindGraph()* and then attach the small bit of Javascript to call `$("#Chart1").dialog("open");` once the page loads.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. For future reference, string script ="$(function () {$(\"#Chart1\").dialog();});";

Comment: Glad it worked. You may want to include a $(document).ready to make sure it doesn't try to fire before the page is ready, especially since you're doing a postback.